# image setup in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, photoshop

My question is, i have an image of size 456x256, resolution 400 and bit depth 32, when i set this image on image-view using(match_parent, wrap_content) it takes a bit less space than its actual size(preferable_image), but when i use another image with size 456x256,resolution 400 and bit depth 24, it takes the actual size of image.

I tried to make image size a little smaller, but it doesn't solved my problem
So have i missed something while creating new image on Photoshop.
Please suggest me something.

Comment: Both images are stored in res/drawable folder

Comment: I haven't calculated it yet.

Comment: The app gets crash while using Log.d() with exception "dividebyzero".

Comment: android.widget.ImageView{_______ V.ED.... ... 0,120-1080,280 #7f0b00bd app:id/include_header_top_logo}

Comment: android.widget.ImageView{___ V.ED.... ... 0,120-1080,504 #7f0b00bd app:id/include_header_top_logo}

Comment: @pskink below data is for depth 32 (preferable) and above is for depth 24.

Comment: I set image on imageview in xml itself.